# Local Deployment/Installation of Kubeflow on Windows

Tags: windows, kubernetes, production, kubeflow

I am facing a major problem in installing Kubeflow locally on my Windows 10 Machine.

Machine Specs - OS: Windows 10, RAM: 16GB

Approaches Tried To Install

1. Microk8s - Not Successful

   I get
   Cannot Install MicroK8s properly, due to “MicroK8s not found error”, along with instance crashing.
2. MiniKube + Vagrant with VirtualBox - Partially Successful

   “Vagrant up” is **very** slow. And sometimes when I manage to open the Kubeflow console locally it crashes after running a couple of experiments. Errors arise from time-to-time and it is hard to pinpoint as to why they occur.
3. Kind - Not Successful

   Out-dated docs and tutorials. Old commands don’t work and the manifests have been moved to another repo.
4. K3s - Not Successful

   Cannot install manifests as it has been moved to another repo. And no updated docs directing as to how we can install it.

Resources Referred:

1. https://kirenz.github.io/codelabs/codelabs/kubeflow-install/#4
2. https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/installation/localcluster-deployment/
3. https://github.com/kubeflow/manifests
4. And official doc of all the Approaches taken

Digging deep what I found was that some guides say that **Kubeflow 1.5.0 is not compatible with version 1.22 and onwards**. And as of now there are no older releases for Kubernetes(lower than 1.22) in the official site. Is this the root cause for the issues that I am facing?

Are there any other way to install and setup Kubeflow locally for Windows? It is hard to find a guide/tutorial or a video which is not outdated.

Answer (score 2):

The current https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/started/installing-kubeflow/ page suggests using a package.

None of the packages are expressly for Windows. The "Charmed Kubeflow" looked promising for an install on a Windows machine, so I went with it.  Here are the steps I figured out after *much* trial and error.

1. Enable Hyper V for Windows.  (If you have Windows Home, see https://www.makeuseof.com/install-hyper-v-windows-11-home/.)
2. https://multipass.run/install.  Choose Hyper V over Virtual Box if you can.  If you cannot, then finish the install while ignoring any VirtualBox related error, and then do Command prompt, `multipass set local.driver=hyperv`. (You may need to restart your computer here.)
3. Command prompt: `multipass shell`
4. Shell:  `exit`
5. Command prompt:  `multipass stop`
6. In the Windows program "Hyper-V Manager", select the VM. Settings:

   - Memory, RAM: 4096, Enable Dynamic Memory.
   - Processor, Number of Virtual Processors = 2.
   - SCSI Controller, Hard Drive, Virtual hard disk, Edit, Action: Expand, New size 50 GB.
7. Command prompt:

   ```bash
   multipass start
   multipass shell
   ```
8. Shell:  (These steps are mostly from https://charmed-kubeflow.io/docs/quickstart.)

   ```bash
   sudo snap install microk8s --classic --channel=1.21/stable
   sudo usermod -a -G microk8s $USER
   newgrp microk8s
   sudo chown -f -R $USER ~/.kube
   microk8s enable dns
   microk8s enable storage
   microk8s enable ingress
   microk8s enable metallb:10.64.140.43-10.64.140.49
   microk8s enable dashboard
   ```
9. Check the status until those items are enabled. Shell:  `microk8s status --wait-ready`
10. Shell:

    *(Note: When I tried to enable `istio` before doing `juju bootstrap microk8s`, the juju bootstrap command consistently failed with the following error regardless of how much memory I allocated to the VM:  `failed to bootstrap model: creating controller stack: creating statefulset for controller: timed out waiting for controller pod: unschedulable: 0/1 nodes are available: 1 Insufficient memory.`)*

    ```bash
    sudo snap install juju --classic
    juju bootstrap microk8s
    microk8s enable istio
    juju add-model kubeflow
    juju deploy kubeflow-lite --trust
    juju config dex-auth public-url=http://10.64.140.43.nip.io
    juju config oidc-gatekeeper public-url=http://10.64.140.43.nip.io
    juju config dex-auth static-username=admin
    juju config dex-auth static-password=admin
    watch -c juju status --color
    ```
11. To access the Kubernetes dashboard:  The Charmed Kubeflow Quickstart instructions for this will not work as-is for your Windows web browser.  Try this:

    - Shell:  `microk8s dashboard-proxy`.  (This will keep running to serve the dashboard until you Ctrl-C cancel, close the window, or shutdown the VM.)
    - Command prompt:  `multipass list`
    - Windows web browser:  https://<ip address for the VM from multipass list>:<port number from dashboard-proxy>, copy-paste the token from dashboard-proxy
12. To access the Kubeflow dashboard:

    - Shell: `microk8s kubectl port-forward -n istio-system service/istio-ingressgateway 8080:80 --address=0.0.0.0`.  (This will keep running to serve the dashboard until you Ctrl-C cancel, close the window, or shutdown the VM.)
    - Command prompt:  `multipass list`
    - Windows web browser:  https://<ip address for the VM from multipass list>:8080

Comment: Hey John, Thank you for the answer. 
I got stuck in step 10 at `juju deploy kubeflow-lite --trust`.
I get an error that says that the pods have disconnected. Have you come across this?

Comment: @L_Jay - Sorry, I don't remember that one or what I did if I did come across it.  Would you please copy-paste the exact error message?  I can't find anything for "pods have disconnected"